# Kivy call function after splash screen is removed

Tags: python, kivy

I created an application in kivy python. I use android. I want to call a function after the splash screen is removed. Because the window is does not re-draw when i run the function the splash screen is shown for many seconds.

My temporary solution is this:

```
def sleep(time,todo):
    Clock.schedule_once(todo,time)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sleep(5,connect)
        return sm
```

Sleep starts when the splash screen appears. Sometimes the sleep time is to short because kivy needs longer to load so the splash screen is not removed when calling connect or the time is to short and i have to wait a few seconds. Is there a way to call a function after the splash screen is removed? I.e. on_built

Comment: There isn't an event specifically for this, but perhaps Clock.schedule(your_function, 0) will work if you put it in the build method, as it will run the code before the next frame (which should mean drawing has begun). Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks. I will try this

Comment: I just wrote a related answer that details Kivy's app life cycle. Check it out @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664181/how-do-i-run-a-function-once-the-form-is-loaded-kivy