# How can I execute a method after kivy has loaded all widgets from a kv file?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

The **init** method cannot be used for this, because the kv file is processed after the object has been constructed. The build() method could be used in the App class, but I need this in a Widget (e.g. non-app) class.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but the Application class has an `on_start()` method that is run just before starting the application main loop. Perhaps you can use that to execute your method.

Comment: See also [this related answer overriding `App.on_start()` to run arbitrary logic after app startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42142596/2809027) – just as suggested by @JohnAnderson above.

Comment: There is an `on_kv_post()` method that is called after all the `kv` rules have been applied for that widget. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the [clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) object for that, you can schedule the execution of that method once or repeatedly after a the time that you want and his usage is very simple

Comment: You mean something like calling "Clock.schedule_once(self.after_created, 0)" from __init__? Yes, I could have figured that out by myself, but I was hoping that there is a concrete method that will be called in the base Widget class, and so it makes inheritance and polymophism possible. Well, if that I what I have to do then I'll do it. :-)

Comment: Yes, but indeed kivy has no concept of a "loaded" state, initial settings of rules are no different from the subsequent ones, and initialisation might even take a few frames if some dispatching use triggers or clock event themselves.