# How do I access ids in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am a beginner to Kivy (though not to Python), and I am struggling to get the ids from a kv string into my main code. I have the following, but the 'print' statement tells me that there are no IDs. The application itself runs with no errors.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

kvString = """
MainScreen:
  id: maincontainer
  cols: 1
  thumbnails: thumbnails.__self__
  GridLayout:
    id: thumbnails
    cols: 3
    rows: 3
    Image:
      source: "test.png"
"""

class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # This prints 0
        print("Ids: {}".format(len(self.ids.items())))

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(kvString)
        return root
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Comment: The `ids` will be empty until the `kv` rules are applied, and that happens after `__init__()` is run. So, you just need to call your `print` later.

Comment: [How can I execute a method after kivy has loaded all widgets from a kv file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237079/how-can-i-execute-a-method-after-kivy-has-loaded-all-widgets-from-a-kv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code, I got a critical warning that there are no screens, and therefore the app will terminate. As soon as I switched `MainScreen` to a screen, it worked out perfectly. Here is the code:

**.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.image import Image

sm = ScreenManager()

#I removed some unnecessary code such as the cols, thumbnail, etc.
kvString = """
<MainScreen>
  GridLayout:
    id: thumbnails
    cols: 3
    rows: 3
    Image:
      source: "test.png"
"""
#NEEDS TO INHERIT SCREEN
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # This now prints 1
        print(f'There are {len(self.ids.items())} id(s)')

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(kvString)
        #Adds the screen
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='screen'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```